# jquery.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:8080/postregistration 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: python, web.py

I tried configuring post data on web py,i configure in controller.py and scripty.js and got error this

[image]

Comment: problem is on server, not on client

Comment: do you have solution ?

Comment: you have to show us the error trace on the server

Comment: how i can trace the error?